# unable to send Byte[] from webform client project to web api service project using c#.working fine with webservice

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have `c# webForm clientproject` and `web api service` project.

I'm sending one file from `c# webForm clientproject` to `web api service` project using `Byte[]`
but at `web api service` project `I'm getting null as Byte[]`
same code working fine with webservice [CODE-IS-HERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx)

winform c# project code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.dll",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;
        Byte[] mybytearray = new Byte[len];
        objfilestream.Read(mybytearray,0,len);
// call service using REST SHARP        
var restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:51737/");
            RestSharp.RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("api/values", Method.GET);
            restRequest.AddParameter("docbinaryarray", mybytearray);
            restRequest.AddParameter("docname", sFile.Remove(0, sFile.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)); 
            restRequest.AddHeader("header", "value");
            RestSharp.IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
        objfilestream.Close();
    }
```

Now in `web api service`

```
// GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get(Byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
        {
            string strdocPath;
            strdocPath = @"C:\Users\ServicetEst\bin" + docname;
            FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray, 0, docbinaryarray.Length);
            objfilestream.Close();
            return "";
        }
```

> But inside web api service i'm getting `NULL` for `docbinaryarray` why
>   so any clue? basically i'm sending one dll file from one solution to
>   another solution using Byte[] but same code working fine with web service.